# UITableView set in Storyboard not showing iOS7

Tags: ios

I have a UIViewController in which I have added a UITableView (all in my storyboard file). I have set the table view to grouped and static cells. In the tableview I have added a few images, UIButtons, etc. When I run the app, the table view does not appear. The tableView is set to its normal class (the UITableView class, and not a custom class). I don't need any of the codes, all I want is the layout of the storyboard to be shown. The tableview is used only as a graphical element (a picture of it would be the same) and not through its features.

Comment: What is the view hierarchy of your view controller in story board (view-wise) ? and does it show in ios != 7 ?

Comment: Well, the view is the initial view controller in my storyboard

Comment: Have you tried adding other things to that view controller, like a UIView with an red background or something. It sounds like you might not be loading the storyboard correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a UITableViewController instead of the UIViewController?
If i'm not mistaken,
Static table view is not support if not embedded inside a UITableViewController..

Try that..